# How to create a new alert rule in Azure using Git Bash?

Tags: bash, azure, git-bash, azure-cli

I have to create a metric alert for SQL databases that will monitor the storage usage. I've created the following script to create the alert because I have more than 600 sql databases, but I have an issue with the scopes parameter., when I run the script I got the following error: ERROR: Scope must be a valid resource id. I appreciate any help. Thank you

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get a list of all databases in the subscription
databases=$(az resource list --resource-type Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases --query "[].id" -o tsv)

# Define Action Group ID
actionGroupId='/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/Cloud_xxx_alerts'

# Iterate through each database ID
for db_id in $databases; do
    # Extract database name and resource group from the database ID
    IFS='/' read -r -a array <<< "$db_id"
    db_name="${array[-1]}"
    resource_group="${array[-3]}"

    echo "Creating alert for database ID: $db_id"

    az monitor metrics alert create \
        --scopes "$db_id" \
        --resource-group "$resource_group" \
        --name "StorageUsageAlert-$db_name" \
        --description "Alert for storage percent usage for database $db_name" \
        --condition "avg storage_percent > 80" \
        --window-size "5m" \
        --evaluation-frequency "1m" \
        --severity 2 \
        --action "$actionGroupId" \
        --tags "xxxxxxx"
done
```

Comment: Please try  `--scopes $db_id`

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a new alert rule in Azure using Git Bash? when I run the script I got the following error: ERROR: Scope must be a valid resource id.

Kindly check if the script contains any typos or syntactical errors that might be the source of the problem.

In the script, you used `${array[-7]}` to get the name of the resource group. However, the resource group location is at the **7th** position, not the **3rd** position, in the `resource ID` of the database.

```
Resource ID of SQL database: /subscriptions/b83cxxxxxxx-b5ba-2b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/<RG-Name>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqlservertestabnew/databases/db2
```

Before running the script, make sure to check the **$db_id** value. If it does not fetch the correct `resource ID`, you can use the following command to check the `database` resource ID.

```
resource_id=$(az resource show --ids "$db_id" --query "id" -o tsv)
```

Here is the updated script that can generate a metric alert for `SQL databases`.

```bash
    #!/bin/bash
    
  # Get a list of all databases in the subscription
databases=$(az resource list --resource-type Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases --query "[].id" -o tsv)
    
    # Define Action Group ID
    actionGroupId= '/subscriptions/<SUB-ID>/resourceGroups/<RG-Name>/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/SQL Database'
    
    # Iterate through each database ID
    for db_id in $databases; do
        # Extract database name and resource group from the database ID
        IFS='/' read -r -a array <<< "$db_id"
        db_name="${array[-1]}"
        resource_group="${array[-7]}"
    
        # Get the resource ID for the database
        resource_id=$(az resource show --ids "$db_id" --query "id" -o tsv)
    
        echo "Resource ID of SQL database: $resource_id"
    
        echo "Creating alert for database ID:$db_id"
    
        az monitor metrics alert create \
            --scopes "$resource_id" \
            --resource-group "$resource_group" \
            --name "StorageUsageAlert-$db_name" \
            --description "Alert for storage percent usage for database $db_name" \
            --condition "avg storage_percent > 80" \
            --window-size "5m" \
            --evaluation-frequency "1m" \
            --severity 2 \
            --action "$actionGroupId" \
            --tags "sqlalert"
    done
```

Alert has been created successfully after running the script.

[image]

The alerts have been configured for all SQL databases.

[image]

[image]